Divide a deck of cards in 2 equal parts. What is the probability of drawing a queen from 1st deck given 2nd deck has at least one queen?
A deck of 52 playing cards has been dividen into 2 equal parts. What is the probability of drawing a queen from 1st deck given 2nd deck has at least one queen?

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Is it safe to assume the division occurs randomly? If so, there are four possibilities (1 Queen, 2 Queens, 3 Queens, 4 Queens). The conditional probabilities for each can then be determined and summed.

Is the answer close to 0.944?

I am sorry to have upvoted this question by mistake (my vote is locked until this question is edited). It clearly does not meet the standards for the site.

@Gwen No, it is not.

Recall, $P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$. Let $X$ be the number of queens in the second deck, and $A$ be the probability the drawn card from the first deck is a queen.
We want to calculate $P(X=k)$. The number of options to to get $X=k$ is the same as choosing $k$ queens out of 4 and then choose the remaining $26-k$ cards, i.e $P(X=k)=\frac{{4 \choose k}{48 \choose 26-k}}{52\choose 26}$.
$P(X\geq 1)=\sum_{k=1}^4 P(X=k)$, $P(A\cap X\geq 1) = \sum_{k=1}^4 P(A|X=k)P(X=k)$, and $P(A|X=k)= \frac{4-k}{26}$.
All of this is enough to calculte $P(A|X\geq 1)$.

This question clearly doesn't meet the standards for the site. Answering it encourages low-quality questions. Please also read the meta announcement regarding quality standards.
